# How to open Radwindow in TelerikMVC3 Razor engine

Tags: razor, telerik-mvc

I have develop a TelerikMVC# application in that i have link button for open radwindow.When i click on this linkbutton how can i open the Radwindow? please help me..

Answer (score 2):

This is how we declare the window:

```
@( Html.Telerik().Window()
    .Name("WindowEditar")
    .Title("Editar")
    .Draggable(true)
    .Visible(false)
    .Modal(true)
    .Buttons(b => b.Close())
    .Width(800)
    .Height(600)
)
```

And here is code to open it using JavaScript:

```
 var popup = $("#WindowEditar").data("tWindow");
 popup.open();
```